# displaying special characters while storing telugu text in mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, special-characters

when I store Telugu text in database it displaying like follows

```
‚ªýdq NŸÄu-ª½Õn-©Â¹× éÂJ-§ŒÕªý
```

How can I show Telugu font in my database.

Comment: set collation of data base to `utf8_general_ci` and table collation to    `utf8_unicode_ci`

Answer (score 0):

you might have default collation in your table's column, you have to set telugu collation for the columns in which you want to store telugu data.

Indic_General_90_CI_AS

Comment: ALTER TABLE tablename ALTER COLUMN columnname VARCHAR(20) COLLATE SQL_LATIN_GENERAL1_CI_AS

Answer (score 0):

You must use collate property to store foreign language

Use something like

select 
    product_name 
from 
    products 
where 
    product_name Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI like 'telugu'